# nested property inside watch event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know my question maybe a duplicate but i cant find the solultion of my problem anywhere
I have an object with some key/values and i want to watch for the changes in all properties,keeping in mind all properties must have separate events here my object

```
data: () => ({
    filters: {
        All: false,
        AllUSA: false,
        AllSouthAmerica: false,
        AllAsia: false,
        AllEurope: false
    }
}),
```

**watch**

```
 watch: {
    "filters.All": function(val) {
        if (val) {
            this.TrafficSource = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.TrafficSource).map(k => ({
                [k]: true
            })));
            this.filters = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.filters).map(k => ({
                [k]: true
            })));
        } else {
            this.TrafficSource = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.TrafficSource).map(k => ({
                [k]: false
            })));
            this.filters = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.filters).map(k => ({
                [k]: false
            })));
        }
    },
    "filters.AllUSA": function(val) {
        alert("both event being called")
        this.TrafficSource = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.TrafficSource).map(k => ({
            [k]: false
        })));
        this.filters = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.filters).map(k => ({
            [k]: false
        })));

        if (val) {
            this.TrafficSource.Virginia = true;
            this.TrafficSource.California = true;
            this.TrafficSource.Oregon = true;
        } else {
            this.TrafficSource.Virginia = false;
            this.TrafficSource.California = false;
            this.TrafficSource.Oregon = false;
        }

    },
    deep: true
  }
```

the problem right now is both the watch events are called event though `filters.All` was invoked, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are assigning `this.filters` inside `filters.All` watcher. Which triggers the watcher on `filters.AllUSA`. I'm surprised you don't get an infinite loop. As a sidenote, you shouldn't overuse `Object.assign()` and I'd also refrain using it with arrays as it's likely not going to produce the expected results in quite a few cases. Besides, it makes your code very difficult to follow/debug, which is the very reason you had to ask the question.

Comment: thats a nice catch, the problem in my case is that i have select/unselect these filters are basically checkboxes

Comment: That is not a reason to use `Object.assign` like you do. If you're willing to create a [mcve] (use codesandbox.io if you need a node-like multi-file editor) I'll take a look and likely come up with a simpler way of doing it. And a lot easier to grasp/follow/debug. As far as I'm concerned you shouldn't even need watchers for it. It can all be done via computed with setters/getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a watcher with options on filters like this:

```
watch: {
  filters: {
     immediate: true,
     deep: true,
     handler(newValue, oldValue) {
     // you can write code to tell you which property is changed since you have
       access to the old and new value here
    }
  },
};
```

this kind of watcher runs immediately when your component loads and then since it has `deep: true` it will trigger if any property in the object its watching gets changed.

now for the code to track what actually changed you can write something like this:

```
// all of this code should be done in the watcher's handler
const newVals = Object.values(newValue);
const oldVals = Object.values(oldValue);
const changedVal = [];
newVals.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (x !== oldVals[i]) {
    const result = Object.entries(newValue).filter(y => y[1] === x).flat();
    changedVal.push(result[0]);
  }
});
```

now you have all the changed `keys` in  the `changedVal` array in the `handler` and you can continue with your logic in the `handler`

**Edit**: also i don't think `changedVal` should be an array, you can set it to the changed `key` and write a `switch...case` based on that