# Vuejs watch property triggers "Maximum recursive updates exceeded."

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to detect if the values of filters were changed to update the `dataChanged` prop, here's the function

```
    watch: {
        /**
         * Watch the editing property.
         * Check if the new value of filters contain a value diiferent then undefined
         *
         * @param  {bool}  value   The value
         */
        filters: {
            handler (newValue) {
                Object.entries(newValue).forEach((prop) => {
                    if (typeof prop[1] === 'undefined') {
                        this.dataChanged = true;
                    } else if (prop[1].length > 0) {
                        this.dataChanged = true;
                    }
                });
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

and it's triggering the following warning

```
Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.
```

Any idea how I can approach this differently?

Comment: What does your `filters` object look like? Are they dependent on `dataChanged`?

Comment: filters: {
                'with_status':                void 0,
                'insurance':                  void 0,
                'contribution':               void 0,
                'ufcs':                       void 0,
                'is_visible':                 void 0,
                'is_active':                  void 0,
                'search':                     void 0,
                'with_more_than_two_regions': void 0,
                'regions':                    []
            },

Comment: No they're not dependent on it

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's happening here, we may need more information. For example, why aren't you checking oldValue in the watcher? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232613/nested-property-inside-watch-event) answer for how to do that. Are you sure this watcher is triggering the error? Maybe put a console.log in the handler?